# Problems with using if, then statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is what I have so far. I have been testing it on c++ shell and it gives me error.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    int main() {

    cout << "Enter a number between 3 and 12: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    if(n>=3 && n<=12)
      cout<<"Good number."endl;
    else
      cout<<"Bad number"endl;

    return 0; //indicates success
    }//end of main
```

Answer (score 4):

`cout`,`cin`and  `endl` are part of the standard library so you need to use `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::endl`. You can use `using namespace std;` on the beginning as well (after the includes, but it is considered as bad programming style).
Change your output to:

```
std::cout << "Good number." << std::endl;
```

Here is a working example:

```
int main() {

    std::cout << "Enter a number between 3 and 12: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    if(n>=3 && n<=12)
      std::cout<<"Good number."<<std::endl;
    else
      std::cout<<"Bad number"<<std::endl;

    return 0; //indicates success
}
```

Comment: You mean `std::endl`? :)

Comment: You could also mention that `std::endl` is for most cases overkill, and `'\n'` is the better choice generally.